# mySQL Multi Join from 2 Statements

Tags: mysql

I've found many similar questions but have not been able to understand / apply the answers; and I don't really know what to search for...

I have 2 tables (*docs* and *words*) which have a many to many relationship. I am trying to generate a list of the top 5 most frequently used words that DO NOT appear in a specified docs.

To this end I have 2 mySQL queries, each of which takes me part way to achieving my goal:

**Query #1** - returns words sorted by frequency of use, falls short because it also returns ALL words ([SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa5fb/3))

```
SELECT `words_idwords` as wdID, COUNT(*) as freq
    FROM docs_has_words 
    GROUP BY `words_idwords`
    ORDER BY  freq DESC, wdID ASC
```

**Query #2** - returns words that are missing from specified document, falls short because it does not sort by frequency of use ([SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa5fb/2))

```
SELECT wordscol as wrd, idwords as wID 
    FROM `words` where NOT `idwords` 
    IN (SELECT `words_idwords` FROM `docs_has_words` WHERE `docs_iddocs` = 1)
```

But what I want the output to look like is:

```
idwords | wordscol | freq
-------------------------
| 8     | Dog      | 3  |
| 3     | Ape      | 2  |
| 4     | Bear     | 1  |
| 6     | Cat      | 1  |
| 7     | Cheetah  | 1  |
| 5     | Beaver   | 0  |




Note: `Dolphin`, one of the most frequently used words, is NOT in the 
      list because it is already in the document iddocs = 1

Note: `Beaver`, is a "never used word" BUT is in the list because it is
      in the main word list
```

**And the question is:** how can I combine these to queries, or otherwise, get my desired output?

Basic requirements: 
 - 3 column output
 - results sorted by frequency of use, even if use is zero

**Updates:**

---

In light of some comments, the approach that I was thinking of when I came up with the 2 queries was:

Step 1 - find all the words that are in the main word list but not used in document 1

Step 2 - rank words from Step 1 according to how many documents use them

Once I had the 2 queries I thought it would be easy to combine them with a where clause, but I just can't get it working.

---

A hack solution could be based on adding a dummy document that contains all the words and then subtract 1 from freq *(but I'm not that much of a hack!)*.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. All you seem to need to do is to add the where criteria from the 2nd query to the 1st one.

Comment: @Shadow If you think you're confused... OMG if you can show me how...  BTW - that's pretty much what I've spent today TRYING to do :(

Comment: 'falls short'? But you need the frequency of ALL words!! What if it's only the LEAST frequent words which are absent from the specified docs!?!

Comment: @Strawberry it's entirely possible that I have missed something but the idea was to FIRST select all the words from the word list that are NOT in iddocs = 1 and then, from the resultant list find the most popular words...

Comment: @SlowLearner by copy pasting the where clause from the 2nd query into the 1st one. This is why I do not get what's the real question here.

Comment: @Shadow - I've slept on this now and realise there were a few issues with the question (lack of clarity in my own mind), please see updates (expected output table). Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see now what the problem is. I was mislead by your statement regarding the results of the 1st query (emphasis is mine):

> returns words sorted by frequency of use, falls short because it also returns **ALL** words

This query does not return all words, it only returns all **used** words.

So, you need to `left join` the `words` table on `docs_has_words` table to get all words and eliminate the words that are associated with doc 1:

```
SELECT w.idwords as wdID, w.wordscol, COUNT(d.words_idwords) as freq
    FROM words w
    LEFT JOIN `docs_has_words` d on w.idwords=d.words_idwords
    WHERE w.idwords not in (SELECT `words_idwords` FROM `docs_has_words` WHERE `docs_iddocs` = 1)
    GROUP BY w.idwords
    ORDER BY  freq DESC, wdID ASC;
```

See [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa5fb/13)

Comment: Thank you, indeed I was terribly confused when I asked the question thank you for sticking with me :)  Still exploring but so far this seems to work; WRT your solution... what are `w.` and `d.`?  Deleting them seems to have no impact to the query... can you point me to some literature that explains this notation further?

Comment: Fantastic, I had no idea what to search for 

Comment: I agree, this would have been difficult to find, particulary because I did not use the `as` keyword. Here I used them only to save myself from typing a few letters. In other cases their use is mandatory, so better be familiar with this concept.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know... I have a much better understanding of this now (still a long way to go...). Curious about your shorthand, in my testing I modified your fiddle to this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa5fb/30 which removes the table aliases. It still works (fewer keystrokes but more difficult to read?)... This is a concept that I will need to become familiar with. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think @Shadow has it right in his comment, you just need to add the where clause like this: [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f861c/13)

```
SELECT 
  `words_idwords` as wdID, 
  COUNT(*) as freq
FROM docs_has_words 
WHERE NOT `words_idwords` IN (SELECT `words_idwords` FROM `docs_has_words` WHERE `docs_iddocs` = 1)
GROUP BY `words_idwords`
ORDER BY  freq DESC, wdID ASC
```

Does this produce the output you need?

Comment: Thanks. Will test in a few hours 

Comment: Thanks, what you have is basically what I kept getting - I've updated the question (see expected output) to explain more clearly, also added more word-doc relationships to your fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa5fb/1  many thanks for your help